# Complexity of computing the similarity between two sequences

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

What is the computational complexity of the best known algorithm for computing the similarity between two sequences (as in DNA or Protein alignment/approximate string matching)?

The similarity is based on:

1. scoring the alignment using [substitution scoring matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_matrix) (for either global or position-specific substitutions of 20 symbols in [Protein alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid#Table_of_standard_amino_acid_abbreviations_and_properties) or 4 symbols in DNA alphabet)
2. [Gap Penalty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_penalty)

Is the linear time of [Burrows–Wheeler transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform) used in [Bowtie](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) and [BWA](http://bio-bwa.sourceforge.net/) short-read aligners the actual state-of-the-art or are there sub-linear algorithms solving the same problem?

[Edit]: Thinking of applying [LSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) for approximate matching that will be sublinear assuming pre-processing/indexing of the reference dataset

Comment: How are you defining "similarity?"

Answer (score 1):

I guess at some point you end up reading the entire sequence so there cannot be a sub-linear time algorithm.

Comment: what about using bitwise operators

Comment: If you are measuring complexity in terms of the sequence length using bitwise operators may be  able to lower the constant but not the order.